# pay calculator but nothing happens

Tags: javascript, html

I work for my father's landscaping business and I want to make a very simple calculator for how much I am owed for the work I have provided. I have something made up for this purpose but I honestly don't know what I have done wrong, can someone help me fix it, I'm sure its something really simple that I Just cant find.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <!-- ALL OF THE INFO GOES HERE -->

  <script>
    var xy = 3; //put in number of yards here
    var xb = 1; //put in number of times bluffs done here
    var xn = 2; //put in number of times newbern done here
    var y = 5;
    var b = 25;
    var n = 15;


    var pay = y * xy + b * xb + n * xn;

    getElementById("Display").innerHTML = pay;
  </script>
  <!-- ALL OF THE INFO GOES HERE -->




  <title> Pay calculater </title>

  <body>

    <p id="Display"></p>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: you need `document.getElementById`. Read the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Answer (score 2):

Your code had 2 issues:

- **"NullReference: reference not found"** If you place the `<script></script>` tag in the `<head>...</head>` you need a `eventListener` to check if the DOM is loaded. You can do this with a `eventListener` like [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event), [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).
- **"Typo"** You forgot `document.` when calling `document.getElementById("Display")`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <!-- ALL OF THE INFO GOES HERE -->
    <title> Pay calculater </title>

    <script>
      const setup = () => {

        let xy = 3; //put in number of yards here
        let xb = 1; //put in number of times bluffs done here
        let xn = 2; //put in number of times newbern done here
        let y = 5;
        let b = 25;
        let n = 15;


        const pay = y * xy + b * xb + n * xn;

        document.getElementById("Display").innerHTML = pay;
      }

      window.addEventListener('load', setup);
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- ALL OF THE INFO GOES HERE -->


  <body>

    <p id="Display"></p>


  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the `getElementById` with `document.` since it is a method on the `document` object.

```js
document.getElementById("Display");
```

Comment: You can't have an XSS attack unless the data crosses sites, which this doesn't. `innerText` `innerHTML` are likely interchangeable here.

Comment: I feel like such an idiot lol

Comment: Yes, but it is a good practice to never use it. :)

Comment: Well, obviously you should use it if you want to alter HTML. so "never use it" isn't right

Comment: I am hesitant to upvote this (otherwise correct) answer, as I think it seems a bit overkill to talk about XSS in such a context - OP is clearly building this strictly for their own personal use and not for anything even remotely resembling a production deployment or in a context which such a vulnerability could expose critical data. In any case it would greatly benefit from the use of a more universally-accepted definition of XSS as opposed to the one here which implies XSS is an attack on the server itself when in reality it is most always an attack on the end users of a vulnerable site.

Comment: :') i was going to edit it to say that but im too lazy. thanks for pointing that out for me

Comment: er, both of those comments

Comment: Considering the discussion here I've edited the answer to (a) focus more on the solution to the problem at hand by removing the extraneous guidance, and (b) provide an illustration more directly relevant to the OP's specific situation.

Comment: I'm sorry that I wasted your time with something so simple

Answer (score 0):

Your script is running before the entire page is loaded. When it runs, there is no "Display" element to update. You need to update that *after* it exists. Your browser console will have good error messages as to what's going wrong.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily incorrect, but this is not the resolution to the error the OP is experiencing at the current moment.

Comment: @JeremyThille I didn't downvote but we should never assume malice.  No evidence downvoters were angry.

Comment: For one, I wasn't able to comment yet.
Regardless, there may be other issues at hand too, but even if those are fixed, it still wouldn't work for the reasons I gave. The question simply asks why it doesn't work.